# how can i use SoundCloud Api for songs in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, soundcloud

Can anyone tell me how can i used Sound Cloud's API of songs in my word press website, so i don't need to upload mp3 files .

Thank you in advance 
Waiting

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing

Comment: In my wordpress backed there is option to insert trackid and soundcloud url ? can you tell me from where i get trackit ?

Comment: There may be more efficient ways of doing this but if you... go to the track **on Sound cloud** > click the **share** button > click on **Embed** > tick the box that says **Wordpress** > look at the code and you will find the unique **track ID** like so  `[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/312797091" ...]` The id is the  number that starts with **312**

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of using soundcloud tracks in your Wordpress website is to simply copy the embed code(**share button below the tracks -> 'Embed' tab -> copy the embed code**)
It looks something like this :-

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/335648999&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

Simply copy this embed code into your Wordpress page.
You don't have to get into any business with the API but still if you want to use the API

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js">
</script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

var track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood';
SC.oEmbed(track_url, { auto_play: true }).then(function(oEmbed) {
  console.log('oEmbed response: ', oEmbed);
});
</script>
```